# Google Apps Script not transferring multiline data from Google Form

Tags: google-apps-script

I have written the following code to generate a pdf from a form response. However, my multiline response (genRemarks) and my score (tSCR) are not being used with the template file I've created, while my timestamp (cDate) is.

```
function onSubmit(e) {
  const rg = e.range;
  const sh = rg.getSheet();

  const cDate = e.namedValues['Timestamp'][0];
  const cBodyComments = e.namedValues['genRemarks'][0];

  //Consequential/Calculated Data

  const cUCS = e.namedValues['Uniform Compliance Score'][0];
  const cPCS = e.namedValues['Protocol Compliance Score'][0];
  const cDCR = e.namedValues['Dignified Conduct Rating'][0];
  const cESR = e.namedValues['Empathy/Sincerity Rating'][0];
  const cSWS = e.namedValues['Structured Work Score'][0];
  const cCCOR = e.namedValues['Chain of Command Observed Rating'][0];
  const cWER = e.namedValues['Work Environment Rating'][0];
  const cOTOTS = e.namedValues['On Task and On Time Score'][0];

  var tSCR = cUCS + cPCS + cDCR + cESR + cSWS + cCCOR + cWER + cOTOTS;

  const invoiceFolderID = '[omitted due to sensitive data]';
  const invoiceFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(invoiceFolderID);

  const templateFileID = '[omitted due to sensitive data]';
  const newFilename = 'OCSO Report_' + cDate;

  const newReportFileID = DriveApp.getFileById(templateFileID).makeCopy(newFilename, invoiceFolder).getId();;

  var document = DocumentApp.openById(newReportFileID);
  var body = document.getBody();

  //start template replacement

  body.replaceText('{{Timestamp}}', cDate);
  body.replaceText('{{genRemarks}}', cBodyComments);
  body.replaceText('{{Score}}', tSCR);

  document.saveAndClose();
}
```

Im a bit new to apps script so any help is welcomed

Comment: I was looking in the stringified JSON of one of my form submissions and I noticed that some of the responses were not in the zero element of the array but the timestamp is `"namedValues":{"Email Address":[""],"":[""],"COL1":["","4"],"COL2":["","3"],"Timestamp":["5/21/2021 19:33:57"],` So you might like to look at the `Logger.log(JSON.stringified(e));` to make sure that your looking at the correct element of the array.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing this: `const cBodyComments = e.namedValues['genRemarks'][0];` to this: `const cBodyComments = e.namedValues['genRemarks'][1];` or whatever based upon your observation of

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {
  Logger.log(JSON.stringified(e));
}
```

I believe the reason I'm seeing  them come in columns other than zero was because I edited the form several times and ended up with multiple columns with the same name so this may not be the issue.  If this is isn't your problem please let me know and I'll delete my answer.